# Storing excel data on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm looking for a way to store data generated by an excel template somewhere on SharePoint 2010. I am very new to SharePoint and still learning some of the abilities etc.

The goal is to store the data created by an excel template when a staff creates a quote using the template. I want to have the quotes available for historic purposes and compare the data.

I understand that SharePoint may not be the correct solution and that there exist much better platforms but right now I'm stuck with SharePoint. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to store the .xls(x) file in a SharePoint library or are you looking to store the rows and columns as data in a SharePoint list?

Comment: Hi there Peter, I am looking for a way to store certain values in cells (e.g the value in G4) as a new item in a list. (So not all of the information within the spreadsheet, just certain cells).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this. SharePoint has a number of webservices that can be used. After doing a heap of searching I found that using the Visual Studio Professional a Excel Workbook Project can be setup with embedded Visual C# code. I am currently implementing this.